# Can't add an element to a one-way simple list

Tags: c, list

I'm not asking about efficiency, further list accessibility or lack of the free() function if it's unnecessary for critical-error free flow of this program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct a
{
    a * nast;
    double v;

};

void add(struct a* list,double d)
{
    list = (a*)malloc(sizeof(a));

    if(!list->nast) goto exception;

    list=list->nast;

    list->v=d;

    return;

exception:
    printf("Cannot add to the list \n");
}


int main()
{
    struct a l;

    add(&l,-602.1);

    return 0;
}
```

The question is: why does it throw

> Unhandled exception at 0x000000013f84107a in list.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xffffffffffffffff.

runtime error and how to fix it?

Comment: Right here: `list = (a*)malloc(sizeof(a));` you lose big. You've dropped the existing list (if any) on the floor and can't get it back.   Sit and think about that until you understand why it is bad. Then you'll be ready to try again.

Comment: it is often better to be more clear with types and variables, in your example you use "a" both as a struct name and a variable name, that is confusing if you find such code in a larger module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many problems with this code, that I think it would be better that you read up more on pointers and argument passing. However here are a few things:

- When you declare the "list" in the `main` function it's already allocated on the stack. You then try to allocate it anew in the `add` function.
- If you want to allocate the node in the `add` function, you need to pass a pointer by reference, i.e. a pointer to a pointer. This is because otherwise the pointer is passed by value and all changes to it (i.e. the actual pointer, not what it points to) will be lost when the function returns.
- The `malloc` function does not clear the allocated memory. If you want that to happen automatically you should use the `calloc` function.
- You don't link nodes into the list, you simple overwrite the list head with the (uninitialized) `nast` pointer.
- You use `typedef` in the structure, but you do not actually define a name for this `typedef`.
- Please, oh please do not use `goto`! It can make your code very hard to read and follow if used to much (and by to much, many would argue that even used once is to much).

---

If I would do this, I would have my `add` function take a reference to a pointer as argument, together with the value to add to the list. I would then allocate a new node for that value, and link it into the list by making the `next` pointer point to the old list, and then reassign the list pointer to point to the new node. If the passed list is `NULL`, then just make the list point to the new node.

Something like this:

```
struct node
{
    struct node *next;
    double       value;
};

void add(struct node **l, const double value)
{
    /* Allocate a new node, use `calloc` to clear the memory automatically */
    struct node *n = calloc(1, sizeof(struct node));

    /* Set the value of the new node */
    n->value = value;

    /* Is the list non-null? */
    if (*l != NULL)
    {
        /* Yes, make the `next` pointer point to the old list */
        n->next = *l;
    }

    /* Make the list point to the new node */
    *l = n;
}
```

This function can the be called like this:

```
 /* Initialize to `NULL` to mark the list as empty */
struct node *list = NULL;

/* Add two nodes, passing the list pointer by reference */
add(&list, 12.34);
add(&list, 56.78);
```

The list now have two nodes:

1. The first node in the list contains the value `56.78`
2. The second node in the list contains the value `12.34`

Comment: In all fairness this is one of the very few uses of goto that find a few defenders. Still, until the OP can write this kind of code error free in his or her sleep you are probably right.

Answer (score 0):

This code needs a lot of work. You get an exception, though, because of this line:

`if(!list->nast) goto exception;`

`malloc` does not zero out the memory it allocates. You allocate a new list structure, but since its not zeroed out, its `nast` pointer holds garbage. The above check fails, and on the next line you unreference this garbage and get the exception.

But really, even if you fix it, this code needs work.

Comment: This is true, but neglects the deal-breaker of an error that comes right before it.

Comment: What error, reallocating the list? It's an error, but not the one causing the exception.

Comment: It does not cause the exception, but it does make the code hopelessly broken. No point in trying to fix the exception while you still have a logic error of that scale.

Answer (score 0):

because your  `list=list->nast;`  let the list be null.